# Permutation and induction

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Each permutation in $A_k$ can be written as a product of 3-cycles of the form (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4),...,(1, 2, k).
I am trying to start this problem by induction but I am having trouble with the base case...
I tried for k=3,
(123)=$(123)^3$,
(312)=$(123)^5$,
(321)=(123)(123),
(231)=(123),
but I can't figure out (213) and (132).

Comment: But you already did, it is $(321)$.

Comment: I have to write it using (123) per the problem... I think

Comment: It is $(123)(123)$, since $(321)$, $(213)$, and $(132)$ are the same permutation.

Comment: Thanks so much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $A_3$ the three permutations are $(1)=(123)(123)(123), (123), (132)=(123)(123)$. Not sure where your confusion lies.

Comment: aren't there 6 permutations? Sorry I am learning this... Also I have to write them using (123)

Comment: No need to apologize. Indeed $A_3$ has 3 permutations. You may be confusing $A_3$ with $S_3$ which has 6 permutations.

Comment: Oh I am confusing the two... What is A then and what is S?

Comment: $A_3$ is a subgroup of $S_3$ consisting of precisely the even permutations. You may ask a separate question in this regard.

Comment: Oh I had no idea. thank you. I think I understand even permutations enough to work my way through it.

Comment: I am looking at #3 on this link https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/halmos-section-28-parity/ what does it mean when they say $(1,2,m+1)^{-1}$? Thanks for your help

Comment: They mean the permutation $(1,m+1,2)$.